# How to create 2 different PDF with the same Context tex source

Tags: context

Is it possible to make 2 (or more) PDF with the same source in Context ?

For example, I want to write a booklet with some algorithmics exercise, and a booklet with the solution wrote in Python (and after Java, C#…)

e.g.

```
\section{First Exercise} %common title to all booklets
\startQuestion %only for "exercise" booklet
  Write a program to get the software version you are using
\stopQuestion
\startPython %only for Python booklet
  print (sys.version)
\stopPython
\startJava %only for Java booklet
…
\stopJava
\stoptext
```

I've tried to use modes, but it did'nt work :(
The Context Garden wiki is not very clear about that.

Thanks to help me :)

Comment: I wrote the wiki article on modes. I will really appreciate if you could help in making it more clear. As an experienced user, it is sometimes hard to imagine what new users find difficult.

Comment: In fact, I'm lost with \startnotmode, \startmode…
And it seems not working if we put modes in new command definition

Comment: @RayLemon You should the read [modes manual](http://www.pragma-ade.nl/general/manuals/mmodes.pdf).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how to do to compile one tex file once and from it get several pdf files. The following works if you are OK with compiling once for each setup:

```
\starttext
\section{First Exercise}
\startmode[Question,all]
Write a program to get the software version you are using.
\stopmode

\startmode[Python,all]
print (sys.version)
\stopmode

\startmode[Java,all]
...
\stopmode
\stoptext
```

Try to compile this the following different options:

- without any option (you should only get the section title).
- `--mode=all` (you should get everything)
- `--mode=Python` (you should get the section title and the Python part)

Of course, you could write a small script to compile several times with different modes enabled.

Comment: It's so simple like that… Sorry for this dumb question :D

Comment: Another option is to leave out the `all` mode, and run `--mode=Python,Java` which will enable both modes

Comment: @Aditya Indeed. I asked about modes some time ago, and I have since then found it convenient to have a mode that includes everything. But your point with the comma separated list is good.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `doifmode`

```
\def\Answers#1#2#3{
    \doifmode{python}{#1} 
    \doifmode{java}{#2}
    \doifmode{csharp}{#3} 
    }

\enablemode[java]
\Answers
{Python code}
{Java code}
{C# code}
```

I sometimes use `doifnotmode`, which can be very useful too. For example here

```
\def\Answers#1#2#3#4{
    \doifmode{python}{#1} 
    \doifmode{java}{#2}
    \doifmode{csharp}{#3} 
    \doifnotmode{python, java, csharp}{\thinrules[color=darkgray, interlinespace=big, n=#4]}
    }

\enablemode[test]
\Answers
{Python code}
{Java code}
{C# code}
{5} % displays 4 lines after the problem
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested your example. It works, but, when I define my own commands like this

```
\definestartstop[question][before={\startmode[question]}, after={\stopmode}]
\definetyping[python][before={\startmode[python]}, after={\stopmode}]
```

When I compile the document above, they print whole text, with any mode selected before ! (--mode=python, --mode=question) !

Maybe I've made a mistake anywhere ?

Comment: You can't invoke a `mode` environment with `before` and `after` keys because when you disable a mode the `\startmode` command tries to read everything untill the `\stopmode` command which doesn't work in this case.

Comment: I think I consider ConTeXt like a programming language :D I'm used to write subroutines.

Comment: It is better to define ```\definebuffer[question]``` and then ```\startmode[question] \definestartstop[question] \stopmode[question] ```, etc.

Comment: Could you show me a little example with these commands, please ?